# Download files from SharePoint as binary and save to disc with ActiveX

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, activex

The target goal is to open an Outlook-Email with attachments from Sharepoint via JavaScript and ActiveX. Unfortunately, I found no way to avoid ActiveX to achieve that goal. Any other ideas are very welcome!

My particular issue is that the binary files from SharePoint, fetched with it's web service

```
"_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + relativeUrl + "')/openbinarystream"
```

are not correctly working the ActiveX ADODB.Stream:

```
var stream = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Stream');
stream.Type = 2;
stream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"; //windows-1252 works too
stream.Open();
stream.WriteText(binaryString);
stream.SaveToFile('D:\\abc3.png', 2);
stream.Close();
```

The file is corrupt. Only Text-Files are working.
I already dealed so much with the charset and it just won't work..
Maybe anyone has had similar issues..

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. It will allow you to download files from document library.

```
http://spsite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://spsite/Documents/sample.docx
```